# php get list of all subdirectories and all files

Tags: php, linux, unix, ls

What is the best way of getting a list of all subdirectories and another list of all files under a given directory in php. I'm okay with a non-pure php code as long as I can use it from php(e.g. a c/java/python/... program). Something faster than pure `recursion`, something built-in in some language(as these things tend to be fast.)

Comment: What's your desired output?  An array?  A nicely formatted string?  The UNIX ```tree``` command gives a nice looking string for displaying directories.  ```find``` lists relative paths, which could be parsed by PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you don't like OOing things, you could perhaps run a loop of opendir() through the results of a find.

```
if (exec('find /startdir -type d -print', $outputarray)) {
  foreach ($outputarray as $onepath) {
    // do stuff in $onepath
  }
}
```

You did specify "not pure PHP", as an option, right?  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator):

```
foreach (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('yourDir') as $file) {
    // you don't want the . and .. dirs, do you?
    if ($file->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($file->isDir()) {
        // dir
    } else {
        // file
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi- RecursiveDirectoryIterator doesn't actually use recursion. It manages a stack frame internally. They probably just chose the name Recursive* because it makes it's functionality obvious.

Comment: This example isnt very useful, as each element in the loop only has private methods

Answer (score 1):

taken from `php.net`s documentation on [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
$path[] = 'starting_place/*';

while(count($path) != 0) {
  $v = array_shift($path);

  foreach(glob($v) as $item) {
    if(is_dir($item))
      $path[] = $item . '/*';
    else if (is_file($item)) {
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dir_helper{
    public function __construct(){

    }
    public function getWebdirAsArray($rootPath){
        $l1 = scandir($rootPath);
        foreach ($this->getFileList($rootPath) as $r1){
        if ($r1['type'] == 'dir'){
            if (preg_match("/\./", $r1['name'])){
            $toplevel[] =  $r1['name'];
            } else {
            if (preg_match("/\d/",$r1['name'])){
                $seclevel[] = $this->getFileList($r1['name']);
            }
            }
        }
        }
        foreach ($seclevel as $sl){
        foreach ($sl as $cur){
            $sub[] = $cur['name'];
        }
        }
        return $result = array_merge((array)$toplevel, (array)$sub);
    }

    public function getFileList($dir){
        $retval = array();
        if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";
        $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
        while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
            if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
            if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
                $retval[] = array(
                "name" => "$dir$entry/",
                "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
                "size" => 0,
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
                );
            } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
                $retval[] = array(
                "name" => "$dir$entry",
                "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
                "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
                "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
                );
            }
        }
        $d->close();
        return $retval;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use php's inbuilt [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

**EDIT**

Something like:

```
$dirs  = array();
$files = array();

$dir = __DIR__ . '/foo';

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(new DirectoryIterator($dir));

foreach ($iterator as $dirElement) {
    if ($dirElement->isDir()) {
        $dirs[] $dirElement->getPathname();
    }
    if ($dirElement->isFile()) {
        $files[] = $dirElement->getPathname();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just like `NikiC`, this is pure recursion, what the OP wanted to avoid. `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` just keeps the programmer from writing his own recursive function.

Comment: Point taken. I thought the OP meant he wanted to avoid a manual recursion implementation. Guess I read that wrong. We could ask the OP to clarify I suppose. Anyway, thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want recursion, I just wrote this up with a few extra bits

```
// $dirs = [];
// Get All Files & Folders in $dir
$files = glob("$dir/*");
for ($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++) { 
    if (is_dir($files[$i])) {
        $files = array_merge($files, glob("$files[$i]/*"));
    //  $dirs[] = $files[$i]; // This can add the folder to a dir array
    }
}
// Remove folders from the list if you like
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        unset($files[$key]);
    }
}
// Clean up the key numbers if you removed files or folders
$files = array_values($files);
```